# Set timeout when loading xml from a URL?

Tags: java, xom

Is it possible to set a timeout when loading an xml directly from a URL?

```
Builder parser = new Builder();
Document doc = parser.build("http://somehost");
```

This may take sometimes minutes, and would be really handy to be able to time this out directly in the library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use build(InputStream inStream) api instead of build(String systemID).

```
URL url = new URL("http://somehost");
con = url.openConnection();
con.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
con.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
inStream = con.getInputStream();
Builder parser = new Builder();
Document doc = parser.build(inStream);
```